# Is there a way to detect if the browser has subpixel precision?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Is there a way to detect if the browser has subpixel precision for elements ?

IE9, unlike any of the other major browsers, has subpixel precision for its elements (an elements width can be 50.25px) and because of that, I need to treat a thing differently.

One way is to use jQuery to detect the browser name and version, but this is deprecated in jQuery and not recommended, instead being suggested that the existence of features should be tested for not the browsers names and versions.

Comment: Upvoted and starred because I have not the slightest clue how subpixels would even work.

Comment: Couldn't you just set the style of a div to be like "50.5px" and then check its width in Javascript, onload, to see if it was rounded off or not?

Comment: Funny, to my knowledge, IE was the *last* of the major browser to implement subpixel precision (or we're talking about two different things ;)).

Comment: @Yoshi Maybe that was for something else, but for the dimensions of elements, all other major browsers have integer values.

Comment: mhm, have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/r2vQD/   (works in every browser I could test [IE, Chrome, FF, Safari])

Comment: @Yoshi on my Chrome install your fiddle results in actual sizes of 34/33/34 for the three divs.

Comment: @Yoshi if you look in the Chrome developer tools and see what values the browser sees internally, they are integer values: 33px 34px 33px.

Comment: @Alnitak, jsgroove: Under "Computed style" -> "width" I get: 33.31666564941406px;

Comment: @Yoshi That float value is just the value specified in the CSS. To see the value the browser implements, look under Properties - HTMLDivElement - clientWidth.

Comment: @jsgroove I don't think that's correct. I'd say the computed style is what's used for further calculations.

Comment: @Yoshi nonetheless, checking whether the divs are "created equal" does appear to be a suitable diagnostic test, per the question (and my answer).

Comment: @Yoshi You can also hover over the element in the HTML code and a tooltip will appear on the element at the top displaying its dimensions. These dimensions are accurate if you will measure the element graphically.

Comment: @jsgroove Of course, but by no means is that a guarantee that the rendering engine will acutally use those displayed values for further calculations. From my experience all major browser (except IE) have, for a long time, handle fractions correctly when it come to displaying elements.

Comment: @Yoshi Please see this updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/r2vQD/1/, and the graphical measurements of it, http://imgur.com/FxUbG .

Comment: @jsgroove I don't get your point? What you're describing is a matter of your display (e.g. your monitor) which issn't capable of rendering subpixels, the rendering engine simply does it's best to help with that. Would your display be able to display those fractions, the rendering engines would render them. But of course we would then have the same discussion on fractions for the next smaller thing after pixels.

Comment: @Yoshi I was just trying to confirm the measurements specified by the Properties - HTMLDivElement - clientWidth settings that I talked about earlier. If float values were supported, regardless of the display of the monitor, shouldn't they be specified there ?

Comment: @jsgroove try: `window.getComputedStyle(HTMLDivElement).width`

Comment: $Yoshi Isn't getComputedStyle refering to the CSS values ? Anyway, I think that this is a more complicated issue, taking into consideration the way that the browser internally sees the values, your points about the display as well, the specification that josh mentioned below, and  the actual display dimensions that the user sees. I guess that there is more to know and search about. The fact remains, however, that there is a difference in how IE9 handles it but to understand it properly there is more to search about.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got the idea that IE9 is the only browser that supports fractional pixel units, but that assumption is totally incorrect.

From [section 4.3 of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#values) (emphasis added):

> The format of a length value (denoted by <length> in this specification) is a **<number>** (with or without a decimal point) immediately followed by a unit identifier (e.g., **px**, em, etc.).

And defining *<number>*:

> Some value types may have integer values (denoted by <integer>) or real number values (denoted by <number>). Real numbers and integers are specified in decimal notation only. An <integer> consists of one or more digits "0" to "9". A <number> can either be an <integer>, or it can be zero or more digits followed by a dot (.) followed by one or more digits. Both integers and real numbers may be preceded by a "-" or "+" to indicate the sign. -0 is equivalent to 0 and is not a negative number.

Therefore, per spec, the `px` length unit *must* support fractional numbers.

To prove this, take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/tnHxy/) in [fullscreen](http://fiddle.jshell.net/josh3736/tnHxy/show/) and use your browser's zoom function to zoom all the way in:

[image: Fiddle screenshot]

In this Chrome screenshot, notice that the 5.5px blue box is indeed taller than the 5px red box.

---

I think the confusion might stem from the fact that the **non-standard** `element.clientHeight` returns a calculated (rounded) *integer* value, and that rounding happens differently in different browsers.

In my fiddle, for the `clientHeight` of the blue `<div>`, IE9 and Firefox 15 at 100% zoom give `6`.  Chrome 22 and Opera 12 give `5`.  In all browsers, the value of that property changes as the user changes the browser's zoom level.

In other words, it's unreliable.

If you want to do calculations with the actual, fractional units of an element, use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle).

```
var el = $('#b')[0]; // the actual DOM element
var height = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(el).height); // => 5.5
```

Comment: I had a lengthier discussion with Yoshi up top but in your example, if you use the developer tools to look into the client settings of the elements at Properties - HTMLDivElement - clientWidth, it will show integer values. Do you know why that is ?

Comment: [`clientWidth`/`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.clientHeight) are non-standard properties that *always return integer (in other words, rounded) values* in all browsers.  In the [updated fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/josh3736/tnHxy/show/), notice that the value of `clientHeight` fluctuates as you change the browser's zoom level.

Comment: The core of the problem was the difference between how IE9 and other browsers handle the display, specifically in my case was that the same layout was displaying differently in IE9 from the other browsers, an issue that I attribute to the way that IE9 handles subpixel precision. From your post as well as from the discussion with Yoshi I understand that there is more to the issue and more to search and be informed about the differences between how each browser handles this. Your post was very informative and useful in coming to this conclusion and your solution is helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an odd-sized container and drop two 50% width elements in it, and find out whether they've been split 50:50 or not.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/jzrQ6/

It returns `false` on Chrome 22.0.1229.79 on MacOS X 10.8.2, and `true` on Firefox 15.0.1.  I don't have MSIE to test it with.

Comment: I get `true` for that in Firefox and IE10.

Comment: Chrome  22.0.1229.79 m on Win 7

Comment: In Chrome, I get false at zoom levels between 50% and 149%, and true at many (but not all) zoom levels outside that range.

Comment: @josh3736 interesting finding!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KAW3d/1/ - in IE6 and IE7 100.5px + 100.5px = 200px (two 100.5px floats fit into 200px container), in IE8+ 100.5px + 100.5px > 200px

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/KAW3d/1/

- in IE6, IE7 and Opera 12.02: 100.5px + 100.5px = 200px (two 100.5px floats fit into 200px container)
- in IE8+, Firefox 15.0.1, Chrome 22: 100.5px + 100.5px > 200px

Answer (score 0):

We had to do some serious pixel-perfect calculations recently, and I needed to check whether the browser was going to support subpixel layouts.  I created a test for use in [Conditionizr](http://conditionizr.com/) or [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) using some other answers as guides:

```
conditionizr.add('subpixel-layout', function() {
    var $testWrap = $(
        '<div style="width: 4px; height: 2px; position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;">' +
            '<div id="subpixel-layout-1" style="width: 2.5px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div>' +
            '<div id="subpixel-layout-2" style="width: 2.5px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div>' +
        '</div>'
    ).appendTo('body');

    var supported = $('#subpixel-layout-1').position().top !== $('#subpixel-layout-2').position().top;
    $testWrap.remove();
    return supported;
});
```

Then you can use with:

```
conditionizr.on('!subpixel-layout', function () {
    // subpixel layout is NOT available
});
```

You should be able to do the same thing in Modernizr with `Modernizr.addTest()`, but I didn't test it.

Obviously I'm using `jQuery` here, but should be pretty simple without it as well.