# Left floated li elements won't stretch full width except in Firefox

Tags: css, list, css-float, html-lists

I'm currently developing my site with a new layout and stuff, and after hours of fiddling around in Chromiums inspector, can't seem to pinpoint why the the content tabs won't fully stretch like in Firefox or IE9. There seems to be a small gap on the right side.

I'm still in the process of tidying the whole css so there are less conflicts, but whatever I do the tabs won't fully stretch in webkit.

Here's a testing page I've set up with the jquery tabs
http://bad-good.org/index.php/Troll_2

Any ideas or workarounds? Looking forward to learning something. Cheers

Comment: It seems to look the same in Firefox/Chrome/Safari for me. Can you add a screenshot of the issue comparing Firefox and Chrome? What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Here's a screenshot
http://img708.imageshack.us/i/scrmf.jpg/

I'm using the latest Chromium nightly. But I noticed the same thing in Maxthon which is also webkit afaik and Opera.

Firefox 4 and IE9 seem to display it properly

Comment: Kaspar: I see. It does look like that in my Chrome also. I just didn't notice it before because it's only a few pixels and I'm silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the `ul` to `width:100%` which renders to `975px`.
The `li` are set to `width:25%` which in theory should be `243,75px`... Chrome makes a floor approximation for the decimals (truncates them, so 243,75 is 243), like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected).

I'd recommend changing the site's width (for example 960px) or working with fixed widths in opposition to percentages.

Comment: Ah, I see, didn't know that :)

Indeed, if I set the main wrapper width to 1000px then it stretches normally as the li is then 244px exactly.

Guess I'll keep the wrapper at 1000px unless I find other problems.

Cheers!