# How can I make that columns in html stay in a row?

Tags: html, css, frontend

```
@media screen and (min-width:450px){
  .dark-blue{
    width: 50%;
  }
  #container2{
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

When this media query triggers, the dark-blue div and the div whose id is container2 will not stay in a row. Specifically, a blank below the dark-blue div is the issue. All I want to know is how to make them symmetrical.  More detail in my github.https://github.com/kmfb/udacityProjects/tree/master/model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gap between two 50% width divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369720/gap-between-two-50-width-divs)

Comment: please post your html as well so we can see the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:450px){
  .dark-blue{
    width: 100%;
  }
  #container2{
    width: 100%;
  }
  #container2 div {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline;
  }
}
```