# formatting table using CSS with top and bottom border

Tags: html, css

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
   li {
      display:inline;
      list-style-type:none; 
      padding-left:1em;
      margin-left:1em;
      border-left:1px solid #ccc;
      }
   li:first-child {
     border-left:none
   }


  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

<table  cellspacing="0px;" style="border-top-width:0.1px; 
 border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#ccc; border-bottom-color:#ccc; 
  border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-width:0.1px;">
 <tr>
    <td>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
          </ul>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

When i am runnning the code in google chrome top and bottom borders are not displayed while in IE they are.
**I also want to increase the line seperator height between li tags**
Am I following the right approach.Can anyone help

Comment: In firefox they are shown, too (tried via JSFiddle, but there's maintainance work going on, so no link. Copy/paste yourself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
border-top-width:1px;
```

and not

```
border-top-width:0.1px;
```

Your measurement is pixels, but your syntax is as if you are using em's.

This issue is also evident in your `cellspacing` tag.

Comment: if i want to increase the hight of separator between li tags...can u help

Comment: To increase the height of separator between li tags. Add the border to the A tag and NOT the LI tag. Set the LI tag to display:block and height: 100%;

Comment: @prerna I found this answer in the following post http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=169547 - 

Using bottom padding on the <li>s works fine in FF, but IE6 doesn't like it for some reason. However, setting a bottom margin on the <a>s (as well as setting them to block display to accept the margin) works fine for both browsers :
Code:
#thumbnails a {margin-bottom: 20px; display: block;}

Comment: It is not increasing the height

Comment: prerna, maybe post the height issue above to a new question?

Answer (score 1):

Change `0.1px` to `1px` One pixel is the smallest screen unit, you can't show `.5` or `.1` of a pixel :) In IE the border is shown because it rounds up to `1px` and other browsers floor it down to `0px`

Comment: how to increase the height of separator between li tags

Answer (score 0):

Pixels are the smallest unit of visual display. There's no such thing as `0.1px;`. While this may work in some situations, it's completely non-standard so don't depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal value for the px (pixel) unit of measure is not allowed. You **cannot** use 0.1 value for px.

If you want to reach smaller width than a pixel (practice that i firmly **discourage**) use the unit of measure em

To understand the different behaviours I suggest this reply: [Are the decimal places in a CSS width respected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected)

[HERE](http://www.paulund.co.uk/decimal-places-in-width-using-pixels) you can find some nice tests.