# jQuery's css(), offset() and position() functions don't return decimal part of CSS properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I set a **CSS** property to a float value, like so:

```
​$('#div').css('left', 123.1234567 );
```

Inspecting #div in the DOM shows that left was set to `123.1234567px`, however all three of these:

```
console.log($('#div').css('left'), $('#div').position(), $('#div').offset() );
```

return the integer value of 123px.

Is **jQuery** trying to be too smart, or is it masking a frailty in the browsers? Do browsers support sub-pixel positioning of divs? Would they if I were using a canvas tag? 
​

Comment: jQuery defaults to px when there is no unit. AFAIK, there is also no fractional pixels.

Comment: This might help in regards to fractional positioning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected

Comment: @Christian Varga: That question has nothing to do with jQuery's implementation of DOM styling whatsoever. Not a duplicate.

Comment: Sure, but it does refer to sub-pixel positioning, which is the *real* question being asked. Edited for the op.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to the known bug in jQuery. See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9628.

I had the same issue with jQuery's `height()`.

[Why does jQuery's height() automatically rounds up the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21777668/1982441)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why your code is not working, the one I tried on JSFiffle seems to be working fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/JBDkr/2/

Comment: I just did, and it alerts "1235.45px" .

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure then :). Though I'd like to know why would you specify pixels in floating points, how is a 0.5px rendered ? 1px being the smallest unit. You can specify floating points if you give the width in percentage or "em" units.