# Why does jQuery's height() automatically rounds up the value?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to calculate the computed height of a list. On IE, these two give different results. On Chrome, the value seems to be always on integer, so I do not get this problem.

```
// gives a string of "353.7px"
window.getComputedStyle(mylist, null).getPropertyValue("height") 

// gives an int of 354
$(mylist).height();
```

How come jQuery drops decimals, or is this a problem with IE?

**EDIT** I was actually lying. This happens with Chrome. See http://jsfiddle.net/jTPk9/

Comment: If anyone is to be blamed, blame IE. jQuery will internally use one of the browser provided methods to get this value, which IE (as always) has got wrong.

Comment: Seems like this happens on Chrome, too. Please see the jsFiddle I added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in jQuery, which shouldn't round height and width values.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9628

**Updated with @CookieMonster's comment**

The current workaround is to use `.getBoundingClientRect().height`, which is cross browser and doesn't round values.

```
document.getElementById("fruits").getBoundingClientRect().height
```

Comment: Just a note for future visitors. Current workaround is to use `.getBoundingClientRect().height`. This works across browsers and does not round up the value.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming here later, this was fixed [in jQuery 3.0](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-width-height-css-quot-width-quot-and-css-quot-height-quot-can-return-non-integer-values) to use the `getBoundingClientRect` API mentioned in the accepted answer. If you're using an older version of jQuery (for example, I was dealing with jQuery 1.12.4), `$(element).width()` and `$(element).height()` will always round to the nearest integer.