# How to achieve $.width() with precision

Tags: javascript

How can I compute the exact width of a block element excluding padding, scroll bar, border, and margin? I know I can use `$(element).width()`, but jQuery does not compute the exact value because it silently rounds up the fractional part. (Please see my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777668/why-does-jquerys-height-automatically-rounds-up-the-value).)

The only way I can think of is to use `.getBoundingClientRect().width` and subtract what's not needed. There's got to be something better than this, but what is it?

Comment: How is this actually different from your previous question? Except for it being width instead of height? Seems the answer is the same and there's no real need for two questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery's height() automatically rounds up the value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777668/why-does-jquerys-height-automatically-rounds-up-the-value)

Comment: Sorry, it is confusing, but this is NOT the same question. `getBoundingClientRect().width` includes padding, scroll bar and border. I want to calculate the width without them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Javascript you can also use getComputedStyle(). Don't know about jquery alternative

```
var element = document.getElementById("a");
alert(window.getComputedStyle(element).width);
```

Comment: Please vot up and check the answer if the above solution is able to solve your problem

Comment: I had to wait a few minutes before I can check the answer. :)

Comment: when using your solution in safari 7.0.2 the number returned is still a rounded value.

Answer (score -3):

jQuery is not silently rounding the value. jQuery is returning the browser computed value. Since browsers can not display a fraction of a pixel the browser itself is computing a more appropriate value for the element. jQuery is actually returning the correct and most precise value.

take this code for example:

```
<div style="width:201px;">
  <div style="width:50%;"></div> <!-- this renders as 100px, not 100.5px -->
</div>
```

There is 1 div with a width of 50% inside an element that is 201px wide.
based on your assumptions, each div should have a width of 100.5px. However, If you inspect the child element using any browsers development tools you will notice that it is actually being rendered as just 100px wide with no fractional value.

Comment: This is incorrect. Please see my previous question referenced in the question.

Comment: Please consider the example I have added to the second half of my answer.

Comment: This is still incorrect. My Chrome browser reports 100.5px. Also, please see this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/35Het/