# Decimal places in CSS percentage

Tags: css, rounding, percentage

OK, I've searched far and wide and come up with nothing more than anecdotal evidence to suggest that there is **no recommended standard behaviour** in the CSS specification for the precision of floating point numbers.

**N.B.** I'm not asking about the [well known sub-pixel rounding problem](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/).

The reason I'm asking is that IE seems to round percentage-based floating point values down to **2 decimal places**, whereas Webkit and Gecko allow at least 3, or even more (I haven't tested).

For example:

```
li {
    width: 14.768%;
}
```

When inspected in Chrome's Web Inspector or Firebug, the `<li>`s are correctly shown to have a width of 14.768%.  However, in IE dev tools (IE9/8/7 mode), they have a width of 14.76%. This causes the actual pixel-based values to be completely out as well.

Can anyone shed any light on this behaviour, or provide a suitable workaround? I'd rather not have to resort to pixel-based values if possible, as the content needs to be fluid width.

I know it's pretty gnarly dealing with this many decimal places, but I'd be very interested to know which, if any, of these browsers is "correct"?

**EDIT**

Firefox *seems* to use the correct percentage values when shown in the inspector (not rounded to 2 decimal places), but is displaying the same behaviour as IE in terms of actual pixel placement.

Comment: Why do you need three-decimal precision?

Comment: I've written a plugin for a fluid-width, responsive carousel. The widths and offsets are all done by dividing the number of carousel items by the total, etc. This unfortunately can end up width 3 decimal places. :/

Comment: If you find yourself needing 3 decimal precision in CSS you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @AntonNiklasson Whilst I do agree, I'm still interested as to any official specification on float precision in CSS. And I've refactored the plugin to use less DOM cloning, resulting in fewer elements, and thus no more 3-decimal precision! :)

Comment: Take a look at these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected

Comment: @AntonNiklasson Stating that someone is doing something "wrong" is not helpful. This is a good/interesting question. Years later I've run into it while editing an open source datatable that allows for resizable column widths. With 2 decimal precision there is jitteriness in the movement, with more it's nice and smooth. So I come searching if there's a reason it was set to round widths at 2 decimal places. Understanding what the spec is, what's allowed, and how it will behave is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are probably many solutions for your problem, I would suggest these:

1. Round on 2 decimals by yourself for all but one, than reduce from
   total width for last one.
2. Use `table` or `display: table`, than the
       browser will fix the widths by itself.

Comment: Seems outdated now

Comment: True, same as my PC :)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming upon this question, this article goes into depth about what different browsers do for percentages with decimal points: https://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/

As for which browser is correct, according to that article:

> The HTML5 Specification doesn’t mention truncating or rounding decimal
>   places. Point 11 deals with decimal places, and says to keep looping
>   until “position is past the end of input, then return value as a
>   length”.