# Center a Wordpress portfolio that uses masonry jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that is using the OrganicThemes - Photographer theme. The demo site can be viewed here: http://organicthemes.com/demo/photographer/three-column-portfolio/

After I customized it for a while, I realized that the three-column portfolio is not centered in the 980px **.row** class. Because this is using Wordpress and PHP, when I inspect it in Chrome, it renders out in HTML, making it harder for me to understand how to fix the problem.

I included a screenshot of the issue I am facing. You can see in the blue box that the third image (aka `<div class="one-third masonry-brick">`) does not hit the 980px mark of the `<div class="row holder-third masonry">`, which makes the second image not center correctly, which basically causes the whole thing to be off.

[image: screenshot]

You can find the different class information in the `style.css` and the `organic-shortcodes.css`, which helps for understanding the `.row` and `.one-third` classes, but I think the real problem is in the `jquery.custom.js` file. I believe the main code in that file that is of concern to the problem is this:

```
/* Masonry ---------------------*/
    function masonrySetup() {
    $('.holder-third').masonry({
    itemSelector : '.one-third',
    gutterWidth : 0,
    isAnimated: true,
    columnWidth : function( containerWidth ) {
        return containerWidth / 3; }
    }).imagesLoaded(function() {
    $('.holder-third').masonry('reload');
    });
```

I have tried to figure out how to fix this, but all I could come up with is how to fix the rendered HTML code, which basically would be to make the second image box be at `left: 340px;` and the third image box should be at `left: 680px;`, which would then make them centered and even.

But I know that this won't be of any help. Somehow I need to fix the Masonry code in the custom jquery file, and possibly change some of the CSS of the div classes.

I hope someone can help explain the problem better, and possibly shed some light on how to fix this problem! Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I added some of the CSS style codes in case that is more helpful to find a solution to the problem.

The layout rendered out in Chrome's inspect element is this:

```
<!-- .container portfolio -->
<div class="container portfolio">
<!-- BEGIN .row -->
<div class="row holder-third masonry" style="position: relative; height: 827px;">
<!-- BEGIN .one-third -->
<div class="one-third masonry-brick" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<!-- BEGIN .one-third -->
<div class="one-third masonry-brick" style="position: absolute; left: 326px; top: 0px;">
<!-- BEGIN .one-third -->
<div class="one-third masonry-brick" style="position: absolute; left: 653px; top: 0px;">
```

What I don't get is how the positioning is working, when the CSS doesn't say absolute? And I don't see any `masonry-brick` class anywhere...where is that coming from?

The `container portfolio` CSS:

```
.container.portfolio {
    background: none;
    overflow: visible;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
.container {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px;
}
```

The `row` CSS:

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 980px;
    min-width: 727px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The `one-third` CSS:

```
.container.portfolio .one-third {
    max-width: 312px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
* Columns *
.one-third { 
    width:30.66%; 
}
.one-half, .one-third, .two-third, .three-fourth, .one-fourth, .one-fifth { 
    position: relative; 
    margin-right: 4%; 
    float: left; 
}
```

And then this is the code that seems relevant to the problem from the template-portfolio-three.php file.

```
<!-- .container portfolio -->
<div class="container portfolio">

<!-- BEGIN .row -->
<div class="row holder-third">

    <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('cat'=>of_get_option('category_portfolio_three'),'posts_per_page'=>of_get_option('postnumber_portfolio_three'),'paged'=>$paged)); ?>
    <?php if($wp_query->have_posts()) : while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $meta_box = get_post_custom($post->ID); $video = $meta_box['custom_meta_video'][0]; ?>
    <?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>

    <!-- BEGIN .one-third -->
    <div class="one-third">

        <!-- BEGIN .postarea portfolio -->
```

I see the `<div class="one-third">` and wonder if code needs to be added to that area in order to fix my problem?

Comment: Try to change inside the `jquery.custom.js` the `gutterWidth` (try with whole number and `whole_number+px` in quotes) and/or `columnWidth`, now it is divided by 3 (1/3th from width of the container).

Comment: @bodi0 Thanks for getting back. When you said to change the `gutterWidth`, try with a whole number and `whole_number+px` in quotes, do you mean like this?? Example: `gutterWidth: '1',` or `gutterWidth: '1px'`? And what do you mean by and/or `columnWidth`? Do you mean I could just go `gutterWidth: 'columnWidth',` and that would solve it? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yep, `gutterWidth: '1px'` and/or `gutterWidth: 1`, for the `columnWidth` I mean not to use function for calculation, as it is now, but fixed (or percentage) value.

Comment: @bodi0 So, apparently I need to have `columnWidth : function( containerWidth )` because it is a fluid design. On the Masonry website http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/options.html under columnWidth, it mentions to use the function if it's a fluid/responsive layout. I also tried changing the `gutterWidth` both ways, but that didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @bodi0 I updated the information a bit up above, and listed out the CSS class codes and the relevant code from the template file. Does this combined with the other information before my update help to make more sense of how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I see something, which may be useful for you - the `.one-third` class has `width:30.66%`  plus `margin-right:4%`, which totals to **34.66%** occupied space, which is **not** 1/3th from 100%, either change the margin, or the width of the class, or define your own class with proper width and margins, overwriting the current ones.

Also, keep in mind, that `IE 8` has some bugs with `max-width/height` combined with `overflow: auto/scroll` (which is used in `.row` and `.container.portfolio` class).

Another thing - different browsers round the floating point values differently - some round them up, some round them down to the whole number, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300163/how-do-browsers-deal-with-non-integer-values-for-height-and-width).