# Why does setting a line-height to 20.16px (from 20.16px) change its height?

Tags: css, google-chrome

An `inline-block` span element with a `line-height` of 20.16px (14.4pt `font-size` * 1.4 `line-height`) has a `height` of **19px** on Chrome.

An `inline-block` span element with a `line-height` of 20.16px (20.16px `line-height`) has a `height` of **20px** on Chrome.

The element inspector gives an identical `line-height` for both elements, but explicitly setting the `line-height` changes the element's height. Try the fiddle to see what's happening:

```css
span {
  font-size: 14.4px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  /* line-height = 20.16px; 14.4 * 1.4 */
  display: inline-block;
}

span.explicit {
  line-height: 20.16px;
}
```

```html
<span>line-height of 20.16px has a height of 19px!!</span>
<br />
<span class="explicit">line-height of 20.16px has a height of 20px</span>
<br />
<br />
<strong>Use inspect element to examine the two span's differing height</strong>
```

Question is: **Why is this happening?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `14.4px` is exactly the same as using `14px`

so `14px`**x**`1.4` = `19.6px`

I tested in both FF and Chrome, and in Firefox they round up to `20px`, but Chrome for some reason just ignore the decimal and stay with `19px`

See relevant [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300163/how-do-browsers-deal-with-non-integer-values-for-height-and-width)

```css
span {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  /* line-height = 19.6px; 14 * 1.4 */
  display: inline-block;
}

span.explicit {
  line-height: 19.6px;
}
```

```html
<span>line-height of 19.6px has a height of 19px!!</span>
<br />
<span class="explicit">line-height of 19.6px has a height of 20px</span>
<br />
<br />
<strong>Use inspect element to examine the two span's differing height</strong>
```

Firefox ScreenShots:

[image]

Comment: Technically, Firefox also rounds `14px`x`1.4` down BUT it rounds `19.6px` up. You can see the question's example: Both elements are `19px` in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Also, in Inspect Element, it appears as `20.16px`. So this seems to be a discrepancy between Inspect Element and the browser's actual DOM metrics.

Comment: See updated answer with Firefox Screenshots, both outputs with `height:20px`