# how to adjust css margin top?

Tags: css

i have a div on my website and i am trying to position this div in css using the margin-top property.

i'm currently using:

```
margin-top: -0.5px;
```

my div is ever so slightly to low when doing this however if i do margin-top: -0.6px; its then too high and im trying to find a value in between 0.5 and 0.6,

is there a way i can use 2 decimal place values like:

```
 margin-top: -0.5.5px;
```

would really appreciate any help with this, thanks?

Comment: `margin-top: -0.55px` would be what you want, however, if your design requires you to use such miniscule values, the problem most likely lays within the structure of the HTML you produce, and could probably be fixed at re-thinking your positioning.

Comment: I don't believe most browsers interpret decimal pixel values. It simply rounds up to one pixel if it's about x.6.

Comment: If you are having trouble with such a minute sub pixel value, you are doing something wrong. Share your code and we can help you out. You can share your direct link or paste code in jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that fractional css pixel ratios are either rounded or truncated.

Conisder the following:

```
div.someclass {margin-top: 0.55px;}
```

and percentages

```
div.someclass {margin-top: 35.55%;}
```

These values get rounded to the nearest percent by most browsers, and truncated by others. Meaning the above 2 examples will be interpreted either as 0.6px / 0.5px and 35.6% / 35.5% depending on the user's browser.

For more information about fractional css values check out this stackoverflow thread: [Are the decimal places in a CSS width respected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected)

How do we fix this? Unfortunately, you can't really but you could try to offset margin fractions by adding some inner padding with a fraction that offsets the margin.

Example:

```
div.outer {margin-top: 0.5px;}
div.inner {padding-top: 0.1px;}
```

This should definitely result in the same output as margin-top: 0.6px but depending on the particulars of your overall css theme you may notice subtle differences.

Comment: Such subtle differences may not be as cross-browser friendly as you wish. Probably a main reason CSS does not support miniscule values in the first place. :)