# Opera & Safari doesn't recognize decimal Pixels?

Tags: safari, opera

For Example... i need an element to be

```
235.5px
```

but in Opera and safari it will show only

```
235px
```

without it's .5. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are the decimal places in a CSS width respected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a half pixel, or a quarter pixel, or a decimal point of a pixel.
Pixels are always whole numbers. The browsers are rendering this correctly.