# Why does Chrome truncate the decimal width of a 100% width table in a div?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, subpixel

I have a div that has a decimal width (e.g. 250.5px) and a table inside of it with a width 100%.  For some reason, Chrome will truncate the decimal portion of the table's width (e.g. from 250.5px to 250px).  When the page renders, the div is rounded up, and there's a 1 pixel gap between the right side of the table and the right side of the div. If I nest a div instead, I don't get this issue.

Why does this happen, and is there a way to get the table to retain the decimal portion?  I'm only having the issue in Chrome; IE10 looks fine.

Demo of issue @ http://jsfiddle.net/7UrHa/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="redDiv">
    <table id="blueTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Content
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#redDiv {
    width: 250.5px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: red;
}

#blueTable {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I understand that Chrome sometimes truncates fractional values, but there seems to be something specific to tables since I don't have the issue with nested divs.

Comment: I can't answer this question because it's erroneously marked as a duplicate, but for future reference it's actually a Chrome issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=241198

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected) for an in-depth explanation.

Basically, if it's a percentage width then yes, it is respected. Chrome does however truncate fractional pixels.

Comment: According to that post, Chrome should keep the fractional value in memory and use that value for calculations; so why would it truncate the value of the table and round up the value of the div?  Also, I'm not sure why a nested div would have the right value but a nested table would not.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell you why Chrome does this, or why it works with a nested div and not a table. To get around this issue, is there a particular reason you cannot nest the table inside another div, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7UrHa/1/)?

Comment: Another workaround would be to set the table width to `100.5%`, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7UrHa/2/).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I can't update the layout because I'm branding an application, and modifying the layout of the page would prevent me from being able to use future updates.  

I found the issue logged on Chromium's code page (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=241198#makechanges). 

As a workaround, I just added a snipped of JavaScript to resize the div.  Maybe a bit over overkill for a single pixel, but it was driving me crazy.