# not able to set 0.px as top value for a div in IE8

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to set 0.1px as top value for my div but the value is considered to be as 0px in IE8.

Other browsers sets 0.1px as top for the div. any solution for this?

Comment: Maybe IE8 understands that a pixel is atomic. ;) Maybe you'll find [this (rather old) article](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/) interesting. It describes the issues browsers are (were) having when rendering sub-pixel elements.

Comment: Well, the "rounding" strategy may be different between browsers, but this is interesting (impact on "hierarchy") : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4309160/961526 . Anyhow, no solution here...

Answer (score -1):

IE 8 and below uses outdated css selectors , properties

Comment: It does. Probably because it is 5 years old, and 5 browser years is about 7.3 million human years. But I don't see how this answers the question.