# How to align submenu to the left of container

Tags: html, css

I have a submenu, that behaves like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jy8vz/2/.

So, this is what I have at this moment: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/2b3utr4wmhcnivc/before.jpg).

I would like a submenu that looks like: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvam9nz68fml4da/after.jpg).

HTML:

```
<div id="mainWrapMenu">
<!-- MenuBar -->
<div id="menuBarWrap">
    <div id="menuBar">
        <ul class="mainNav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Prima Pagina</a>
                <ul class="subNav">
                    <li class="subNavStyle">Click pentru a ajunge pe pagina principala in pozitia initiala.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="servicii.html">Servicii</a>
                <ul class="subNav">
                    <li class="subNavStyle">Click pentru a va familiariza cu serviciile pe care salonul nostru vi le pune la dispozitie.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="cursuri.html">Cursuri</a>
                <ul class="subNav">
                    <li class="subNavStyle">Scoala de formare.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="promotii.html">Promotii</a>
                <ul class="subNav">
                    <li class="subNavStyle">Aici poti afla promotiile si ofertele pe care ti le punem la dispozitie. Oricine poate beneficia de acestea.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="galeriefoto.html">Galerie Foto</a>
                <ul class="subNav">
                    <li class="subNavStyle">Portofoliul Salonului Estetique Studio.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                <ul class="subNav">
                    <li class="subNavStyle">Unde ne puteti gasi si cum ne puteti contacta.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="facebook.html">Facebook</a>
                <ul class="subNav">
                    <li class="subNavStyle">Pentru actualizari in timp real, ne puteti urmari progresul pe Facebook.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
<!-- END MenuBar -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mainWrapMenu { 
    width:1000px; 
    height:auto; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    background:#FFF;
}


#menuBarWrap { 
    width:auto; 
    height:52px; 
}

#menuBar { 
    width:auto; 
    position:fixed; 
}

.mainNav { 
    list-style-type:none; 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
    text-align:center; 
}
.mainNav ul { 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
}
.mainNav li { 
    float:left; 
    width:142px; 
    position:relative; 
}
.mainNav a { 
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:#666; 
    font-size:20px; 
    display:block; 
    line-height:52px; 
    background:url(images/buttonBgrd.jpg); 
}
.mainNav a:hover { 
    background:url(images/buttonBgrdHover.png); 
    color:#fc951e; 
}

.subNav { 
    display:none; 
    text-align:center; 
}
.subNav li  { 
    width:1000px; 
    background:#fc951e; 
}
li:hover .subNav { 
    display:block; 
}
.subNavStyle { 
    list-style-type:none; 
    text-align:center; 
}
```

How can I get to the desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to adjust these CSS classes to properly handle the positioning (basically you want to position the subNav (`.mainNav ul`) absolutely relative to the `.mainNav` not the individual `.mainNav li`'s)

```
.mainNav { 
  /*add this*/
  position: relative 
}
.mainNav li {
  /*remove this   position: relative;   and optionally add the position:static*/
  position: static;
}
.mainNav ul {
  /*add these*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

Live Example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/jy8vz/3/)

Comment: I did exactly this and look how it looks on the website: [link](http://estetiquestudio.com/test/)

Comment: You made `.mainNav li` `position: absolute;` it should not have any positioning declared or it should be `position: static;`.

Comment: I would like to say that even comparing I did not see that difference. Thank you JRulle for the patience.

Comment: No problem... just a little additonal FYI... your seven li elements of 142px width will not fill the 1000px wide area (you will actually be short 6 pixels). this is causing your white space on the right hand side of the menu li elements

Comment: Yes... That I know... will fix it with 142.86px lol. Any other better ideas? As I guess there must be some tricks maybe.

Comment: Take a look at this question: [**decimals in css width**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected) -- in my opinion, percentages may be a better way to go here (14.2857%)