# Is it safe to occupy 100% width when using DIV

Tags: html, css

Consider the code below

```
<div id=container>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    background-color:red;
    overflow: auto;
}
#container div {
    float: left;
    width: 22.15%;
    margin-right: 3.8%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
}
#container div:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

The width and margin occupy the 100% (22.15% *3 + 22.15%) of the container. Is it cross browser safe to do this? Or should I only occupy like 98% for safe?

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/NSndR/

Answer (score 1):

That is mostly true, just beware that border's and margins do not count towards that 100%.  For example, if your div is 100%, but it has a 2px margin, it is actually 100% + 4px... same goes with borders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 100% percent width (*including* padding, border and margin) is safe across browsers (guess what, even Internet Explorer). Percentage values should also work as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected) SO question.