# Are sizes with decimal valid and how will the browser treat them?

Tags: css

I'm using http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/jstyleparser/ to parse the CSS and the issue is that when i try to save to a file by using rule.toString() the sizes found in the rules (width, padding, etc.. anything with a number) are saved with a decimal.

So for example if in the original CSS file width was 80px now when saving I get 80.0px

Will this be an issue? How do browser treat this?

The size remains the same but it just adds that decimal.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem. At least IE6+ support decimal values in CSS.

Not related to your question since you have only .0 decimals in your case but a little about using decimal values in CSS in general:
If you have something like `margin-left: 1.5px;` set to an element, it wouldn't make much sense since 1px is the smallest unit on the screen but `font-size: 1.5em;` would be valid.

Comment: Note that a very small padding-top value (say, 0.01px) can be used to stop margins collapsing without any padding actually being rendered.