# CSS Width Property

Tags: css

What does this type of **WIDTH** declaration means? (See Source [HERE](http://theme-fusion.com/avada/))

```
#content {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    width: 71.1702%;
}
```

Comment: It means #content will be 71.1702% of its container object

Comment: If you are wondering about the decimal places, read this: [Are the decimal places in a CSS width respected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is saying that the `div #content` will be `71.1702%` of it's parent's `width`.

example:

If parent's `width` is `100%` of screen, then `#content` will be `71.1702%` of screen.

If parent's `width` is `400px`, then `#content` will be `71.1702%` of `400px`.

Comment: Strictly, it is the nearest block container ancestor box, which is often, but not necessarily the parent. For example, it would not be the parent if the parent was an inline element.

Comment: I think I remember reading this somewhere but I have yet to run into a time where I've used it without it being the width of its parents. Kinda one of those "technically but in production..." sorta things.