# CSS parent element height is rounded wrong if child height is fractional

Tags: html, css

So, I have a little list of `<li>` elements with height like 60.78px, and parent `<ul>` element takes exact 60px height, that causes child element to overflow.

However, if `<div>` have fractional height, parent `<div>` element will have right height.

What should I do to fix `<ul>` element height to fractional?

Comment: Can you please post a working fiddle of your code?

Comment: I will try to attach it later

Answer (score 0):

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309051/3666810) there's a very nice explanation as to what happens to decimal pixel values.

Comment: it is not about displaying, it is about wrong calculating, where child element  is bigger than its parent somehow