# iPhone5 and 6 image scaling issue

Tags: html, html-email

I am working on an email with two rows of three images. It works well throughout all email clients until I get to iPhone5, 6 and 6s where in iPhone5 the first two images seem to be shrunk even further then the last image. Making a white line between the first and the second row.(see the image attached).
In iPhone6 and 6s it is only the first image that is causing this issue. 
Here is the code as well.
I have tried to place all images in individual tables, add width to individual tables, TDs and image tags, I even turned PX to percentage and nothing seem to be working. Anybody has any idea?

Cheers

```
    <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="ffffff" class="100plr">
                <tr>
                    <td width="11" class="hide"></td>
                    <td valign="top" align="center">
                        <table width="579" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="100p">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" align="center">
<!--                                Row one-->
                                    <table width="579" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="100p">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" align="center">
                                                <a href="##" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://uploadlibrary.com/emosaic/martin/kuoni/html/images/img388x344.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display:block;" class="100p" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="top" align="center">
                                                <a href="##" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://uploadlibrary.com/emosaic/martin/kuoni/html/images/img388x344.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display:block;" class="100p" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="top" align="center">
                                                <a href="##" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://uploadlibrary.com/emosaic/martin/kuoni/html/images/img388x344.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display:block;" class="100p"/></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
<!--                                End of Row one-->

<!--                                Row two-->
                                    <table width="579" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="100p">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" align="center">
                                                <a href="##" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://uploadlibrary.com/emosaic/martin/kuoni/html/images/img388x344.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display:block;" class="100p" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="top" align="center">
                                                <a href="##" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://uploadlibrary.com/emosaic/martin/kuoni/html/images/img388x344.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display:block;" class="100p" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="top" align="center">
                                                <a href="##" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://uploadlibrary.com/emosaic/martin/kuoni/html/images/img388x344.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display:block;" class="100p" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>  
                                    </table>    
<!--                                End of Row two-->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10" class="hide"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>   





   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>email template</title>
    <style>


         @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300); /*Calling our web font*/

        /* Some resets and issue fixes */
        #outlook a { padding:0; }
        body{ width:100% !important; -webkit-text; size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }     
        .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }
        .ExternalClass {width:100%;} 
        .backgroundTable {margin:0 auto; padding:0; width:100%;!important;} 
        table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
        .ExternalClass * {line-height: 115%;}   
        a:visited{color:#dddbdc;text-decoration:none;}
/*      div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }*/

        /* End reset */

        @media screen and (max-width: 630px){


            *[class="mobile-column"] {display: block;} 

            *[class="mob-column"] {float: none !important;width: 100% !important;}          
            *[class="hide"] {display:none !important;}          

            *[class="100p"] {width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}                    

            *[class="condensed"] {display: block;}

            *[class="center"] {text-align:center !important; width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}            

            *[class="100pad"] {width:100% !important; padding:20px;} 

            *[class="100padleftright"] {width:100% !important; padding:0 20px 0 20px;} 

            *[class="100padtopbottom"] {width:100% !important; padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;} 

            *[class="padleft50p"] {text-align:left !important;}


            *[class="100grad"] {width:100% !important; height:1px !important;}

            *[class="cwNumbs"] {font-size:40px !important;}

        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
            *[class="100p"] {width: 100% !important; height:auto !important;}
            *[class="100pm"] {width: 100% !important; height:auto !important;}
            *[class="100plr"] {width: 100% !important; height:auto !important; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;}
            *[class="100prl"] {width: 100% !important; height:auto !important; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;}
            *[class="100plrn"] {width: 100% !important; height:auto !important; padding: 0 70px 0 70px;}
            *[class="100pr"] {width: 100% !important; height:auto !important; padding: 0 30px 0 0;}
            *[class="100pt"] {width: 100% !important; height:auto !important; padding: 10px 0 0 0;}
            *[class="100pb"] {width: 100% !important; height:auto !important; padding: 0 0 20px 0;}
            *[class="100pbn"] {width: 100% !important; height:auto !important; padding: 0 0 30px 0;}
            *[class="100pad"] {width: 100% !important; height:auto !important; padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;}
            *[class="hide"] {display:none !important;}
            *[class="center"] {text-align:center !important;}
            *[class="mobile"] {width: 100% !important; height:auto !important; display:block !important; max-height:none !important;}
            *[class="heading1"] {font-size: 29px !important;}
            *[class="heading2"] {font-size: 26px !important;}
            *[class="heading3"] {font-size: 15px !important;}
            *[class="heading4"] {font-size: 17px !important;}
            *[class="apptext"] {font-size: 15px !important;}
            *[class="text"] {font-size: 20px !important;}

        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 373px) {
            *[class="heading1"] {font-size: 24px !important;}
            *[class="heading2"] {font-size: 22px !important;}
            *[class="heading3"] {font-size: 15px !important;}
            *[class="heading4"] {font-size: 15px !important;}
            *[class="apptext"] {font-size: 13px !important;}
        }
    </style>


</head>
```

[image: Screenshot of issue]

[image: Screenshot of Code]

Comment: It is more helpful to paste the code into the question. Using a screenshot makes it really hard for someone to edit and test changes to the code. You can also embed the screenshot of the issue in the question so people are more likely to see it.

Comment: Oh cheers, dude, sorry im new on here. here is the code.

Comment: That's fine :) Thanks. What's the class `.100p` look like? Or if you could share your stylesheet that would be great.

Comment: Use tables it's an email.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the error but I noticed that the TDs don't have defined width and the placeholder images are actually 172px wide rather than (579 divided by 3). Try adjusting some of the values to match the first container table.

Comment: The "class100p" gives width="100%" and height="auto" when scaling down on mobile...

Comment: also I just added the head of my email above. Cheers again for your help

Answer (score 0):

It appears in my iOS Simulator (in xcode) that the computed sizes of the three identical images in a row on an iPhone 5S are 93x82, 93x82, and 94x83, respectively. The computed sizes of the table is 280px, which when divided by 3 is 93.3333px. So that might explain why the widths are different. It appears iOS will not use fractions-of-pixels for width while some other clients/browsers do.

What I might do in this situation is hide the images themselves on mobile, moving them to the background of the anchor tag it's living in, changing the anchor to display block with a width and height of 100%.

There's an exploration on fractional widths here: [Are the decimal places in a CSS width respected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected)