# Positioning: style and computed style have different values safari

Tags: javascript, safari, letter-spacing

I have some trouble with letter-spacing style in Safari 7.0. I have an input into which I enter the value letter-spacing style for text in the page. 
But after I enter values, computed styles and ruled style have difference.
For example I enter 36.4px letter-spacing.
This is my computed and ruled style:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTFGk.png)

I tried change letter-spacing with console, but i have the same trouble
[trouble](http://prntscr.com/9dy7vh)

How can I fix this trouble?

Comment: I think your css has relative and stuff which starts to calculate your css widths. For this example (not recommended) make everything absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General, Decimal notation will work for `%` not `px`. Refer the below SO Answer:
[Are the decimal places in a CSS width respected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I set the "%" value to "letter-spacing"?

Comment: share your code in the question / jsfiddler first to discuss further