# border-collapse using HTML attribute

Tags: html

Is there an HTML attribute available equivalent to the CSS property `border-collapse: collapse;`?

I am trying to achieve the same 1px border with HTML only, and not using css.

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
<td>Row 1</td>
<td>Row 1</td>
<td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>Row 2</td>
<td>Row 2</td>
<td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 12):

You could try `cellspacing`.

```html
<table border="1px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
<td>Row 1</td>
<td>Row 1</td>
<td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>Row 2</td>
<td>Row 2</td>
<td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> Note: **cellspacing** doesn't overlap borders of adjacent cells, which CSS property does.

Comment: So it's `cell-spacing` or `cellspacing`?

Comment: @justinas Typo, Thank You though.

Comment: it is not possible to make exactly 1px border only with html ?

Comment: It does not accept decimals for pixels(like 0.5px), so **NO**.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected) for more.

Comment: @FelixAJ, I would like to know, why cant you use CSS?

Comment: @Felix A J, did you got, what you asking for?

Comment: @divy3993 `cellspacing` only makes it 2px border.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cellspacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#attr-cellspacing) or [cellpadding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#attr-cellpadding) but it's deprecated in HTML5

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why you want to stop using CSS because that is what css do
you can use boostrap the css is included inside.
for more info go to w3chools

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```