# 3 div with the same css, but they're not the same height

Tags: html, css

[image: look at this photo]
my point is to make something like left window, but it ended up as what you can see in right photo. 3 div with the same css code, but they have different height.

```css
span div {
    background: #262626;
    height: 1.5px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    border-radius: 15%;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</span>
```

Comment: Change `height` property to `2px` and it sould work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using fractional values in `px` unit for height. change it to integer value. It will work.

```css
span div {
  background: #262626;
  height: 2px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  border-radius: 15%;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</span>
```

**UPDATE**

AFAIK fractional pixels or sub-pixels are rounded or considered differently in different browsers. In chrome, it should display these `divs` with equal height. but it may vary according to screen size.

Run the below snippet and try to `zoom-in` the screen, you will see at some point these `divs` are having equal `height`. But at another zoom levels `divs` will display with uneqaul heights.

More info: [Sub-Pixel Problems in CSS](https://johnresig.com/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/)

```css
span div {
  background: #262626;
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  border-radius: 15%;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Height doesn't work in decimals. Some browser covert it to round off but all browsers  have a different strategy when rounding sub-pixel percentages. So use it integer. Also detailed explaination are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected)

```css
span div {
    background: #262626;
    height: 3px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    border-radius: 15%;
}
```

```html
<span>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `1.5px` is very small to be shown on the screen. Make it `2px`.

```
span div {
    background: #262626;
    height: 2px; /* changed to 2px */
    width: 20px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    border-radius: 15%;
}
```