# Getting CSS top value with fractional pixels of an element exactly as it is set in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have a bit of a puzzling issue. I am trying to set the CSS top using jQuery 3.5.1 in Firefox and I was expecting to be able to retrieve it again as the same value. Try this on any `div` element:

```
$('#test-div').css('top', 1.11111);
alert(parseFloat($('#test-div').css('top')));
```

The alert is:

```
1.11667
```

It is not the same as `1.11111` due to the way different browsers handle [fractional pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected). It seems to work alright in other browsers I've tested it with (Edge and Chrome, for example, which seem to have a six digit granularity).

When I inspect the HTML, the value is set correctly from the jQuery side to `1.11111`. Is there any way to fetch this value **exactly** as it is set in the DOM such that I get back `1.11111`?

Comment: Short answer: no. You're entirely at the mercy of the browser.

Comment: using vanilla js the same result?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But, I see the value is correct in `$('#test-div').parent().html()`, so arguably, I could parse that...but I am looking for a more elegant solution as to how to parse that...

Comment: Exactly my point. You could hack around the HTML text in the DOM, but that's ugly and not an acceptable solution. The alternative is to use the value returned from the CSS engine of the browser, which is what gives you the unreliable sub-pixel values. Do you *really* need sub-pixel accuracy? In terms of the UI There's no difference between `1` and `1.11111`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yup. In this case, I really do. I am okay with parsing the DOM as a solution. Just want something a bit more performant.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a `data-top="1.1111"` attribute instead? Then the value is guaranteed to no lose precision and you can set `top` in CSS however you need

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I guess I could also just store it in a variable as someone pointed out.

Comment: I can explain why I need it...so, I am writing a virtualized table in JavaScript. It supports millions of rows, and has custom vertical scrollbars. Upon mouse wheel move, I move the scroll bar down by a height relative to the height of one row, thus adjusting its top value. Obviously in Firefox, one row’s height relative to itself is too granular with a data set of large enough size...seems to work okay on Safari, Edge, and Chrome, though. Even mobile. So, I’m alright with people cranking the mouse wheel on Firefox just to meet minimum granularity!

Comment: Using a variable works okay in my situation...I'll go with that. Actually its working really well for me.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Here’s how it turned out in the end. A real beauty IMHO. https://www.nocturis.com/liquid-data-tables/demo.html

Comment: Just ran it (outside SO, with jQuery 3.5.1 on **W10-x64**): Firefox Developer Edition v.79.0b8-64bits **1.11111**, Chrome/Edge **1.11111**, IE11 **1.11**, Vivaldi 3 (Chrome) **1.11111**, Pale Moon 28.11 (old FF clone) **1.11667**

Comment: Ditto  **Android 9**: Firefox SE **1.11667** Chrome **1.11111** Samsung internet **1.11111** Edge **1.11111** For now I would say that it is a Firefox Standard Edtion problem...

Comment: Same results for `alert(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#test-div')).top));`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.getComputedStyle(element).top`

This was exact for me.

Comment: This does not give back the same value for me in Firefox.